# Getting malformed numeric constant:

Tags: spring-mvc, hsqldb

I want to execute the following query:

```
@Query("select p from Permission p where p.userIds in ?1 ")
List<Permission> getPer(List<Long> usrsIds);
```

And my entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Permission extends AbstractAuditable<Permission, Long>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4484607117586062823L;

@ElementCollection
private List<Long> userIds;
```

And I call the query as follows:

```
 monitoringPermissionRepository.getPer(usrsIds);
```

But when I execute the query I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: malformed numeric constant: .
```

Comment: If more clarification needed please ask and help me please...

Comment: To be clear, you need the every value of the `userIds` list of the `Permission` Entity to be contained in the list of longs you supplied?

Comment: Have you tried `@Query("select p from Permission p where p.userIds in (:usrsIds) ")
List<Permission> getPer(@Param("usrsIds") List<Long> usrsIds);`?

Comment: @geoand No. Still getting the same exception..

Comment: Can you also try the same query as I mentioned above but without the parenthesis around `:usrsIds`? Thanks

Comment: whether it is a problem with  @ElementCollection?????

Comment: I am not exactly sure how ElementCollection works with JPQL lists. Try what I mentioned above

Comment: ok. I will get back to you after trying that..

Comment: @geoand No. same exception  malformed numeric constant: .

Comment: I'm out of ideas I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you are fetching a list inside another list.